# python subprocess.Popen is creating duplicate file and writing to duplicate file instead the original

Tags: python

This is my code:

```
outputFile = 'C:\\myfileslog\\log\\' + timestr + str(myrandam) + '_' + "out.res"
binaryExe = 'C:\\Users\\xxx\\Desktop\\test\\test2.9.exe'
input = binaryExe + ' -o ' + outputFile + [inputParameters]
subprocess.Popen(input ,bufsize=65,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
```

While running above code, i am getting 2 files created as below:

1) 20181004-124704_0.45529096783117506_out.res

2) 20181004-124704_0.45529096783117506_out.ÿÿÿÿCPI

I have already tried giving `stdout=outputFile` - which not writing anything on the file. Please help, i dont want duplicate file to be created which is causing issues

Comment: the files are probably created by your executable program. There's no way Popen creates 2 files. Wouldn't it be a nul terminating issue from the exe side?

Comment: `input = binaryExe + ' -o ' + outputFile + [inputParameters]` looks fishy. What is `inputParameters ?` you cannot add strings to lists.

Comment: Thanks for replying. inputParameters is indeed a String (sequence of string which i am passing as parameters, similar to executing it in command prompt). Yes, it definitely looks like the file is created by executable program, But it is creating similar file name i gave with some unknown characters appended.

Comment: I mean `input = binaryExe + ' -o ' + outputFile + [inputParameters]` cannot execute successfully.

Comment: inputParamters = "AB141 TPAL 3C3A8C snapshots 512 mpp 1 trs 1 rsp 1 performance-tier 1"                                                                                                   And then the actual code is: input = binaryExe + ' -o ' + outputFile + inputParameters                                                                                                  It is executing fine both through python and also in command prompt.                 But the actual issue is , that i am not understanding why 2 files are created, and one of them is blank and other has proper data

Comment: I think you want stdout=file(outputFile, "w"). (Or 'a' instead of 'w' if you want to append rather than overwrite).

Comment: please [edit] your question instead of commenting. Else it's really a mess :)

Comment: sorry, it was my mistake. i was using - input = binaryExe + ' -o ' + outputFile + inputParameters   and at the same time i was doing - f= open(outputFile ,"w+")         i commented that "open" and hence it created only one file this time.                     But the file created name is stil having ".tÿÿÿÿCPI" magic characters instead of ".txt"